# Sefardi Keeping Second half of Sefirah

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sefirat-ha-omer

The Shulchan Aruch writes that one should not get married between Pesach and Shavuos until Lag B’Omer; likewise regarding haircuts, since then the Talmidim of Rabbi Akiva stopped dying. Therefore, one may do so from the next day - Lad B’Omer.

The Rema then mentions another popular minhag, to start the Sefirah restrictions from Rosh Chodesh Iyar, and not from right after Pesach. This Sefirah lasts until shortly before Shavuos, excluding Lag B’Omer itself. This has come to be known colloquially as ‘Second Sefirah’.

Can a Sefardic Jew choose to keep this "Second half" of Sefirah?

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 493.3

> יש נוהגים להסתפר בראש חדש אייר, וטעות הוא בידם.‏
>
> הגה: מיהו בהרבה מקומות נוהגים להסתפר עד ראש חדש אייר, ואותן לא יספרו מל"ג בעומר ואילך, אעפ"י שמותר להסתפר בל"ג בעומר בעצמו. ואותן מקומות שנוהגין להסתפר מל"ג בעומר ואילך, לא יסתפרו כלל אחר פסח עד ל"ג בעומר. ולא ינהגו בעיר אחת מקצת מנהג זה ומקצת מנהג זה, משום "לא תתגודדו" (דברים יד, א) וכל שכן שאין לנהוג היתר בשתיהן. (דברי עצמו):‏

Comment: If I remember correctly, some Moroccans keep the minhag you mention; but they start from pesach.